# Unable to connect to wireless after switching from Gnome to KDE

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, networkmanager, wicd

I changed my desktop environment from GNOME to KDE yesterday, and after that I'm unable to connect to any wireless networks. I can find wireless networks, but for some reason unable to connect to them.

How can I rectify this ?

Comment: I changed to title to make it more search friendly, hope you don't mind.

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer and edit this post so that it reflects a question ?

Comment: @Sathya I marked it as community wiki, because I figured that approach was dishonest. :/

Comment: you can form your own question and answer :) Just post the solution as an answer, I'll edit the question

Comment: @Sathya okay,I posted my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution.

Most guides on the subject suggested removing Network-Manager and installing WICD, but I didn't have ANY internet, so this wasn't an option. Here's how I fixed it:

First, I edited `/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-setting.conf` file so that it contained `Managed=True`

Next, I ensured that `ath5k` module was not blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/`. To do this, just run

```
grep -r "ath5k" /etc/modprobe.d/
```

and confirm that nothing is returned.

I followed this up with

```
killall nm-applet
nm-applet --sm-disable
```

and rebooted my system. When it came back up, I actually WAS connected wirelessly again, but the nm-applet was still missing from my notification panel. However, now that I had internet, I was able to install `wicd`

```
sudo apt-get install -d wicd
```

And to ensure that I could connect through wicd instead of NetworkManager, and I uninstalled Network-Manager via

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager
```

I hope this helps anyone else out in my situation, because were I not bald already I would have pulled my hair out last night.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrew, I hope it helps someone !